# ASP.NET Provide Styling for TextBox

Tags: asp.net

I am using a multiline textbox as following:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="200" Width="500" ReadOnly="true" Font-Names="calibri" Text="Terms and Conditions Next text will go over.. >
```

What I need to do is to only make Terms and Conditions in bold. Rest of the sentence is not in bold. I tried using a span with a style of bold but that did not affect anything.

How do I do styling for a Textbox? Keep in mind this is a read only textbox.

Comment: why dont u use div or span if it's readonly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, u need this
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx

```
 <script>
        function onContentsChange() {
            alert('contents changed');
        }
    </script>

    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        ID="txtBox1" 
        TextMode="MultiLine" 
        Columns="50" 
        Rows="10" 
        Text="Hello <b>world!</b>" />

    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender 
        ID="htmlEditorExtender1" 
        TargetControlID="txtBox1" 
        OnClientChange="onContentsChange" 
        runat="server" >            
    </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is more than a regular textbox, you should either use devexpress or ajax toolikt, or some other ajax libraries.

you might consider looking for library that gives you rich formatting abilities